# Mysql Load two table column value into Single

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table in database.

```
Table1 -> Name
Table2 -> Name
```

What will be query to get all the "Name" from Table1 and Table2 into single Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns the value from the Name column from Table1 and the Name column from Table2, concatenated together into a single resultset.

```
SELECT t1.Name FROM Table1 t1
 UNION ALL
SELECT t2.Name FROM Table2 t2
```

(This was my understanding of what you were looking for.)

If you want just a "distinct" list of Name values (exclude duplicate occurrences of the same value), then remove the `ALL` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Select name from table1
union
Select name from table2

Answer (score 0):

You can select data from two tables like this.

> SELECT CONCAT(table1.name,table2.name) as Name FROM table1,table2;

and in case table1.name is A and table2.name is b you get

Name = AB

Comment: btw, this creates all possible combinations with the two tables, should have mentioned this btw :D

Comment: It's unlikely the OP wanted a Cartesian product of all rows from both tables. But then again, the specification is loose enough that this may be what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name FROM Table1 NATURAL LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2.
```

This will give you a list of only non-duplicate names from Table1 and Table2.

Comment: This query will return Name values from Table1, including any duplicate Name values in Table1. This has the potential for generating additional duplicates, when multiple "matching" rows are found in Table2. Name values from Table2 will not be included in the result set.